# Qual a importância dos atributos Integrity e CrossOrigin?

Tags: html, segurança, cdn

Andei dando uma pesquisada, mas ainda me permanece essa dúvida. Atualmente alguns frameworks, seus `link` e `script` estão vindo com atributos `integrity` e `crossorigin`.

Ex.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Qual seria a real importância desses atributos? É uma regra ou opção de CDN's? E qual seria o impacto ou que relevância teria caso esses atributos fossem removidos?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Isso é feito para garantir que os arquivos não foram modificados. O `sha-384` é um resumo criptográfico da família SHA-2, enfim é uma hash criptografia. Esse recurso é sensível a qualquer alteração, ou seja qualquer alteração no arquivo, mesmo que mínima, gerará uma hash diferente, *acredito que essa explicação seja minimamente suficiente*.

O `integrity` serve justamente para que possa garantir que um arquivo alterado não seja baixado pelo usuário.

**Imagine a situação:**

1. Vários sites usam o `https://maxcdn.../bootstrap.min.js`.
2. Uma pessoa, mal-intencionada, consegue obter acesso ao servidor que está armazenando este arquivo.
3. Essa pessoa altera o arquivo. Esta alteração é um JavaScript que tenta localizar por `form` e quando preenchido envia os dados para ele.

**Resultado:**

Todo mundo que usava este arquivo (`https://maxcdn.../bootstrap.min.js`) terá o site comprometido, porque irá carregar um JS alterado, que irá enviar informações (ex. login/senha) para o tal pessoa mal-intencionada, afinal grande parte dos sites possuem formulários de login/senha, logo todos que digitarem vão enviar informações para esse atacante.

Isso pode ser comparado ao um XSS, só que ao invés de um usuário *injetar* um código, você mesmo injetou isto, indiretamente.

*Existe outras maneiras de prevenir o caso acima, usando o [CSP (Content-Security-Policy)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Security/CSP/Utilizando_Politicas_De_Seguranca_De_Conteudo), ela inclusive pode obrigar que você informe o `integrity`, mas isso está fora de questão aqui.*

---

Como evitar isso? Teoricamente usando hash.

Uma vez que este arquivo não será alterado, você coloca:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Isso irá garantir que este arquivo não foi alterado e permanece idêntico. Se um invasor alterar o arquivo ele irá ter outra hash, que não será equivalente ao que informou no `integrity`, o navegador irá ignorar o arquivo baixado.

---

Você pode usar o https://www.srihash.org/ para obter as hashes de arquivos já hospedados, *óbvio você deve fazer isto quando o arquivo estiver confiável, se não você vai calcular a hash do arquivo modificado*.

Lógico que também poderá utilizar funções da própria linguagem ou bibliotecas como `openssl` para calcular a hash dos arquivos e utiliza-las.

O uso de mecanismos automáticos, usando openssl (*ou `hash_file`, no PHP*) é bastante útil se você utiliza um CDN (exemplo CloudFlare), você pode criar um `init()`, *função iniciada ao executar*, que já calcula as hashes dos seus próprios arquivos, *que posteriormente será armazenado no CDN*. Assim, se o CDN ficar comprometido o seu site não sofrerá grande impacto, *ao menos não que comprometa a seriamente a segurança*.

---

O motivo do uso do SHA-384 ao invés de outro algoritmo da mesma família (ex. SHA-512) ainda não encontrei de fato. Entretanto, o motivo pode ser porque o SHA-256 e SHA-512 são vulneráveis ao *length extension attack*, *mas não encontrei uma informação que prove que este é o motivo*.

Answer (score 6):

`integrity` é autoexplicativo: verificação de integridade. Isso é um *checksum* para garantir que o script que foi baixado não teve nada corrompido nem é uma versão desatualizada no seu HD, independente do motivo.

`crossorigin` é pra habilitar CORS, e com isso informações de erros de execução são recebidos pelo seu site. Só funciona se o CORS estiver habilitado do outro lado, que no caso dos CDN's, isso normalmente está ativo.

Fonte:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-scripting.html#element-attrdef-script-crossorigin

Comment: Agradeço a resposta, mas ainda não compreendi a real importância disso, se é regra ou opção e qual o impacto que teria, caso fossem removidos.

Comment: @LucasHenrique Um exemplo do `crossorigin` estiver desabilitado: digamos que aconteça uma exceção no seu bootstrap e que ela gera uma mensagem como "estilo não definido" ou qualquer coisa do tipo. Essa mensagem do erro, mencionando em que linha do JS está acontecendo o erro com a call stack só iria ser passada pro seu site se `crossorigin` estiver habilitado. Senão você só iria receber um erro genérico de JS, sem dizer call stack, sem descrição do erro.

Comment: Já o `integrity` você provavelmente não entendeu o que é checksum. Checksum é um método de gerar um hash, um texto, que represente o arquivo. Se o conteúdo do arquivo for diferente, o checksum é diferente. Usar `integrity` garante que o checksum seja verificado, evitando que um arquivo que foi baixado e esteja corrompido seja usado, ou até mesmo alguma versão errada do arquivo. Se o checksum do arquivo do browser não bater com o citado na tag ele vai baixar denovo até que os dois checksums sejam equivalentes.

Comment: Perfeita colaboração @DH. eu também tinha essas dúvidas, obrigado cara!